# Listview listener not getting called

Tags: android, listview, listener

I have button, which on clicked displays a listview and on clicking the listview item it must print something on logcat. I implemented this one in such a way that the list view and its listener are present inside the button onclick listener.

All is working well except the listview listener is not getting called(i.e. nothing is printing on logcat when clicked on listview item)

Here is my listener.

```
public class MyClickListener implements View.OnClickListener {
    LinearLayout parent;
    LayoutInflater layoutInflater;
    Context context;
    Home home;

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        parent = (LinearLayout) home.findViewById(R.id.main_view);
        View childLayout = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.mylayout, (ViewGroup) view.findViewById(R.id.list_layout));
        parent.addView(childLayout, 0);

        LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) home.findViewById(R.id.main_view);
        ListView list = (ListView) layout.findViewById(R.id.list);
        list.setAdapter(new MyListAdapter(context));
        lsit.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
                System.out.println("hello Android");
            }
        });
    }
}
```

mylayout.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:id="@+id/list_layout"
              android:orientation="vertical"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:padding="15dp">

    <ListView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/list"
        android:padding="15dp"
        android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
        android:dividerHeight="5dp"
        android:listSelector="@android:color/transparent"
        android:cacheColorHint="@android:color/transparent"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Home.java

```
public class Home extends Activity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);    
        setContentView(R.layout.home);
        Button button= (Button) findViewById(R.id.but);
        button.setOnClickListener(new MyClickListener(this,this,layoutInflater));
    }
}
```

home.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:background="@color/background">
...
    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:id="@+id/main_view">
    </LinearLayout>
.....
```

Can anyone help

Edit 1

MyListAdapter.java

```
private class MyListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
        String[] items;
        LayoutInflater inflater;
        Context context;

        public MyListAdapter(Context context) {
            this.context = context;
            Resources resources = context.getResources();
            items = new String[]{resources.getString(R.string.q1), resources.getString(R.string.q2), resources.getString(R.string.q3)};
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return items.length;
        }

        @Override
        public Object getItem(int i) {
            return i;
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int i) {
            return i;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int i, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
            View view1 = view;
            inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            if (view == null)
                view1 = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_layout_item, null);
            TextView question = (TextView) view1.findViewById(R.id.itemtext);
            question.setText(items[i]);
            return view1;
        }
    }
```

list_layout_item.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:id="@+id/item"
              android:layout_width="fill_parent"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              style="@style/itemStyle">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/itemtext"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="8dp"
        android:drawableRight="@drawable/disclosure_indicator"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Are you sure that you have added the button in your XML file.

Comment: yes but i didn't pasted all of it. moreover it is going up to the listview only listener is not getting called

Comment: ohhh, got your problem. You have implement the Listview itemclick inside the button click. Means its only possible with Button click and in really which never exist. :)

Answer (score 0):

Remove this code from your onClick() method and implement outside of that onClick() method. Just set Adapter there, but implementation is wrong og onItemClickListener().

```
lsit.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
                System.out.println("hello Android");
            }
        });
```

Comment: where should i write it then and what is wrong on onItemClickListener()

Comment: parent = (LinearLayout) home.findViewById(R.id.main_view);
        View childLayout = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.mylayout, (ViewGroup) view.findViewById(R.id.list_layout)); remove these all code from that method, initialize it in onCreate(). Just set adapter there, and put onItemClickListener() into onCreate() as well.
        parent.addView(childLayout, 0);

        LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) home.findViewById(R.id.main_view);
        ListView list = (ListView) layout.findViewById(R.id.list);

Comment: You mean to extend MyClickListener class to an Activity and implement some code in onCreate(). I will try.

Comment: You can do this code in your onCreate() as well, without extend MyCLickListener. try it, it will work.

Comment: Just now i checked when i am implementing the adapted in this way      String[] values = new String[]{"Android List View", "Adapter implementation"};
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(home, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, android.R.id.text1, values);
        faqList.setAdapter(adapter);    its working correctly, but when i am using custom adapter its not coming.

Comment: woking when using ArrayAdapter, not working when using custom adapter. I want to use custom adapter

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that in your list_item_layout doesn't have any element is stealing event, like button or TextView with setClickable(true).

Comment: yes you are correct how to resolve. i kept android:clickable="false" on textview but in vain.

Comment: If don't solve it yet, post the code of your list_layout_item and MyListAdapter, it's easier to give a precise answer.

Comment: I have added the MyListAdapter and list_layout_item

Comment: pradeep, strange, it looks be right, what are you setting in @style/itemStyle?

Comment: me too, I previously customized the list item with a lot of views but i didn't faced this problem. and in itemStyle i kept the background item which linked to a drawable.xml file where i defined the corners, stroke, gradient.